# How can I convert date time from time zone A to time zone B in Joda time?

Tags: java, jodatime

Imagine I have some datetime value coming from one system, and a timezone information (source and target time zones) coming from another. I need to convert the datetime from source to target time zone.

For example, let's say I get a datetime in the Moscow time zone. I need to convert it to the Berlin time zone. How can I do it using Joda Time?

```
private static final String TIMEZONE_BERLIN_ID = "Europe/Berlin"; //$NON-NLS-1$

private static final DateTimeZone TIMEZONE_BERLIN = DateTimeZone
    .forID(TIMEZONE_BERLIN_ID);

private static final DateTimeZone TIMEZONE_MOSCOW = DateTimeZone
    .forID("Europe/Moscow"); //$NON-NLS-1$

@Test
public void testDateTimeConversion() {
    final Date sourceDateTime = new DateTime(2015, 3, 15, 12, 55).toDate();
    // We assume that sourceDateTime is in TIMEZONE_MOSCOW. We want to convert it to TIMEZONE_BERLIN.
    // Note that the conversion should work regardless whether sourceDateTime contains any timezone
    // information. It must be converted from TIMEZONE_MOSCOW to TIMEZONE_BERLIN (regardless of whether
    // a timezone is specified in it).
    final Date expectedResult =
        new DateTime(2015, 3, 15, 12 - 2, 55).toDate(); // At 12:55 in Moscow, it is 10:55 in Berlin.
    final Date actualResult =
        new DateTime(sourceDateTime, TIMEZONE_MOSCOW).toDateTime(
            TIMEZONE_BERLIN).toDate();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

Why does `actualResult` contain wrong datetime?

`new DateTime(sourceDateTime, TIMEZONE_MOSCOW).withZone(TIMEZONE_BERLIN).toDate()` doesn't work, either.

Comment: `java.util.Date` objects do not contain timezone information - they are little more than wrappers around a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 GMT. So this is not going to work if the result is stored in a `java.util.Date`. There is no such thing as a `Date` object with a specific timezone.

Comment: @Jesper I don't need a time zone in `actualResult`, as long as it is equal to `15.03.2015 10:55` (Moscow time minus 2 hours). Right now I get `15.03.2015 13:55` and I don't understand, why.

Comment: Because you're pretending that you have a `Date` object that is in a specific timezone (such as Moscow time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to work:

```
@Test
public void testDateTimeConversion() {
    final Date sourceDateTime = new DateTime(2015, 3, 15, 12, 55, TIMEZONE_MOSCOW).toDate();
    final Date expectedResult =
        new DateTime(2015, 3, 15, 12 - 2, 55, TIMEZONE_BERLIN).toLocalDateTime().toDate();

    final DateTime timeInMoscow =
        new DateTime(sourceDateTime, TIMEZONE_MOSCOW);
    final DateTime timeInBerlin = timeInMoscow.toDateTime(TIMEZONE_BERLIN);
    final Date actualResult = timeInBerlin.toLocalDateTime().toDate();

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried your test and it fails when I run it.

Comment: It runs on my machine. If it fails on yours and you are in a different timezone (not Moscow), then it means that `sourceDateTime` and/or `expectedResult` are somehow bound to the timezone of the machine, where the test is executed.

Comment: @Jesper I modified the way `sourceDateTime` and `expectedResult` are created (added the timezone in the constructor). Theoretically, it should work now regardless of where the machine is located.

Comment: With your fix it works (adding timezone to `sourceDateTime`), but it's still based on the fundamentally flawed idea that you can have a `Date` which represents a date and time in a specific timezone. This might fail when things like daylight savings time shifts play a role.

Comment: I don't understand, why it is wrong. All routines in the system operate only on hours, minutes and date data. These hours-minutes-date tuples are `java.util.Date` instances. As long as all parts of the system agree on what timezone a particular ´hours-minutes-date´ is, everything is OK. You think it's not. Why?

Comment: Because a `Date` is not directly a set of day / month / year / hour / minute / second / millisecond - it's a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT. The day / month / year / hour etc. are calculated from that. What the day / month etc. are depends on things like daylight savings changes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A `java.util.Date` object does not contain timezone information. It's just a wrapper around a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT. You cannot have a `Date` object that is in a specific timezone. A `Date` object always refers to an "absolute" point in time. You should not pretend that the `Date` object contains a date and time in a particular timezone (such as Moscow or Berlin timezone).

Instead, you specify the timezone when you format the `Date` object for display, by setting the timezone you want to see the `Date` in on the `DateFormat` object:

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));

Date now = new Date();

// Note: The same Date object, but displayed in different timezones
System.out.println("The time in Berlin: " + df1.format(now));
System.out.println("The time in Moscow: " + df2.format(now));
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have to pass the converted datetime to another routine as a `java.util.Date` object. I don't need to output the converted datetime, but to process it further.

Comment: Then that other routine is probably also faulty, if it thinks it's getting a `Date` object that is in Berlin time...

Answer (score 0):

I think this one addresses your concern. Just convert this logic to JUnit then it will work.

```
    DateTimeZone TIMEZONE_BERLIN = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin");
    DateTimeZone TIMEZONE_MOSCOW = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow");

    //moscow timezone 12:55
    DateTime sourceTimeMoscow = new DateTime(2015, 3, 15, 12, 55, TIMEZONE_MOSCOW);
    //berlin time expected 10:55
    Date expectedResult = new DateTime(2015, 3, 15, 10, 55, TIMEZONE_BERLIN).toLocalDateTime().toDate();
    //get actual result in Berlin in reference to Moscow
    Date actualResult = new DateTime(sourceTimeMoscow, TIMEZONE_BERLIN).toLocalDateTime().toDate();

    //for display purposes
    System.out.println(expectedResult); //expected result Berlin Time
    System.out.println(actualResult); //actual result Berlin Time
```

I hope this solution addresses your issue.